# how to have a centered row of columns in semantic ui similar to bootstrap or foundation?

Tags: css, semantic-ui, css-frameworks

New to semantic ui, while I'm loving some of the features here, the simple task of having a centered row of columns is baffling me here.

I essentially want to the same outcome of doing this in foundation:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-12 columns"></div>
</div>
```

This would give me a centered content area of 1000px. Is there a way to accomplish this with semantic ui?

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to Semantic UI, but from documentation I could figure out how the column structure can be used as follows.

```
<div class="twelve column row">
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.